# 2 or 4 Digit Date Validation with Javascript String Replacement

Tags: javascript, string, debugging, validation

**EDIT: To anyone making the same mistake I did in asking this question, please look for my amended answer below which demonstrates a MUCH cleaner solution to this problem.**

Trying to permit user entry of either 2 digit or 4 digit date format and allow both to pass validation but autocorrect the 2 digit format with the 4 digit equivalent with the assumption that the leading 2 digits should be the same as the current leading 2 digits.

I'm having trouble with the javascript `replace()` function.  This line:

```
            input.replace(enteredDate, year);
```

is not working as expected. In the context of the `spine.js` framework I'm using, the `input` refers to `$(event.target)` and appears to be correct everywhere else in manipulating the `input` field where the validation should be occurring.  Ultimately, I want to replace the original string found in the input field with the fully concatenated one (which I haven't built out yet), but for now, how can I replace the contents of `input` (where input is `var = $(event.target)`) with the var `year` assigned here:

`var year = currentYear.charAt(0) + currentYear.charAt(1) + unparsedYear;`

Here is the full code for the function I have so far, which is throwing the following error in reference to the `.replace()` line -  `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'`

```
validateDate: function(event) {

        var input = $(event.target);
        var enteredDate = input.val();

        input.destroyValidationMessage();

        var pattern = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2})|(\d{4})$/;
        var result = enteredDate.match(pattern);

        if (result !== null) {
            var month = parseInt(result[1], 10);
            var day = parseInt(result[2], 10);
            var year = parseInt(result[3], 10);

            var unparsedYear = parseInt(result[3], 10);
            var unparsedYearStrLength = unparsedYear.toString().length;
            if ( unparsedYearStrLength < 4) {
                var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear().toString();

                var year = currentYear.charAt(0) + currentYear.charAt(1) + unparsedYear;
                alert('Autocorrected year will be ' + year);
                input.replace(enteredDate, year);
            }

            var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
            var isValid = date.getFullYear() === year && date.getMonth() === month - 1 && date.getDate() === day;

        } else {
            input.createValidationMessage('Invalid Date');
            input.addClass('invalid'); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: if `input` is a DOM element, don't you want to `replace` the content, a la `input.val(new_value)` and not the actual `input` element?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for that - you should post it as an answer so you can get reputation for it.

Comment: Why are you validating with a regular expression (which will quite happily pass `34/13/1956`) and then checking actual Date validity after your processing? Surely it would be better to check the entry is a valid Date before processing? Particularly since Javascript will happily turn a two-digit year into a four-digit year by itself.

Comment: Because I need to sanitize user input, not change it.  The native Date object will auto-convert 2/30/12 to ---> 3/1/12 and this is unfortunately not what I'm going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above:

`input` is a DOM element, but you actually want to replace the *content* of the element vs. the element itself, so use `input.val(new_value)` and not the actual `input` element.